# App not displayed in full screen on iPad Pro Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have created an iPad app in Xcode 7.3. Every works fine on iPad 2, iPad Retina etc.. but my problem is when my app is loaded with the **iPad Pro simulator**. The app works fine but is not zoomed to display at full screen (*approx 2 3rds of the screen*). When creating my app I did not set and constraints as on previous versions of Xcode,  iPad apps would automatically zoom there native size to fit on the iPad Pro. I do not have a iPad Pro to check if my app will zoom to fill the screen on an actual device. If I were to submit my app to the App Store would it be refused ?

If required, is it possible to submit an iPad App without supporting the iPad pro ? (possibly by not suppling iPad pro screen shots in iTunes Connect).

If required I can post some screen shots

Comment: Is your app using launch images or a launch screen file? You must use a launch screen file to support the iPad Pro.

Comment: xcode 7.3 comes with a default LaunchSreen.storyboard to launch a screen file. Ive placed a 2048 x 2731 image in the LaunchSreen.storyboard viewController. As expected, my app loads with the launch image full screen with the iPad pro but then loads my app at the incorrect (not full size ) scale as before.

Comment: @Pete please let me know the solution. I am facing similar issue